# Click event is not firing on button of each row of a datatable used in Angular 2

Tags: angular, datatables

I need to get the value of a row in a datatable. I have the codes that creates the buttons but when I click on it, nothing happens. Even just a simple alert doesn't happen. Please see my code below.

**.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getUsers();
  }

  getUsers() {
    this.us.getUsers()
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.users = data;

      var table = $('#datatables').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        responsive: true,
        data:this.users,
        columns:[
          {
            data:"Id"
          },
          {
            data:"FirstName"
          },
          {
            data:"MiddleName"
          },
          {
            data:"LastName"
          },
          {
            data:"UserName"
          },
          {
            data:"Email"
          },
          {
            data:"DateAdded"
          },
          {
            data:"IsActivated"
          },
          {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '<div class="btn-group">' +
                        '<button type="button" (click)="onView()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs dt-view" style="margin-right:16px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>' + 
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dt-edit" style="margin-right:16px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>' + 
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs dt-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></div>'
          }
        ],
        language: {
          search: "_INPUT_",
          searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
        }
      });

    })
  }

  onView() {
    alert("View button clicked");
  }
```

below is how I implement it in the html
**.html**

```
<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0"
    width="100%" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>FirstName</th>
            <th>MiddleName</th>
            <th>LastName</th>
            <th>UserName</th>
            <th>Email </th>
            <th>DateAdded</th>
            <th>Activated</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

Can you please show me how to this right? Thank you.

**EDIT**
Added the html part.

Comment: I don't know why you are using jquery version of dataTable in angular app. why you are not using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-datatable npm version of dataTable in your web app. Try this

Comment: I could use Mat-Table but I need to use the Jquery datatable.

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: It's this one => https://angular-hxdbgi-iwhthe.stackblitz.io

Comment: share `editor url` of stackblitz not `app url`.